# LINKED TABLE WITH QUERY INSIDE CONTAINS "/" IN COLUMN NAME

Tags: h2

I'm trying to create an H2  link to an oracle database with this query :

CREATE LINKED TABLE MyLinekTable('oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver','jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:orcl','login','password','(SELECT "/BIC/ZBSARK" as FLOW FROM MYTABLE)');

And i get this error :

Error: ORA-01424: missing or illegal character following the escape character
; SQL statement:
CREATE LINKED TABLE P710_ParamFRS2('oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver','jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:orcl','login','password','(SELECT "/BIC/ZBSARK" as FLOW FROM ZPARAM_FRS)') [1424-197]
SQLState:  22025
ErrorCode: 1424

I tried to escape the "/" with "\" and [] and \Q..\E but no sucess !

My remote table (on oracle) contains 2 columns : /BIC/ZBSARK and PLANT

[create table MYTABLE(
 "/BIC/ZBSARK" varchar(20),
  PLANT varchar(20))]

When i try with the PLANT  column instead of the "/BIC/ZBSARK" column, this work well :
CREATE LINKED TABLE MyLinekTable('oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver','jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:orcl','login','password','(SELECT  "PLAN as FLOW FROM MYTABLE)');

I tried to escape the "/" with "\" and [] and \Q..\E but no sucess !

Can some one help or has the same problem ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an H2 database bug. An issue was filled about it on GitHub:
https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/2073

The fix will be available on the standard version after h2-1.4.199.

If needs, you can build H2 from its current sources and use the generated jar.
Sources are here:
https://github.com/h2database/h2database
Building instructions are here:
https://h2database.com/html/build.html#building